# posix threads with c language

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

```
#include <pthread.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 10

void *work(void *i){
      int f = *((int *)(i));
      printf("Hello, world from %i with value %i\n",
             pthread_self(), f);
      pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv){
      int i;
      pthread_t id[NUM_THREADS];
      for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i){
            if(pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, work, (void *)(&i))){
                  printf("Error creating the thread\n"); exit(19);}
      }
      return 0;
}
```

the output is supposed to be :

```
Hello, world from 2 with value 1
Hello, world from 3 with value 2
Hello, world from 6 with value 5
Hello, world from 5 with value 5
Hello, world from 4 with value 4
Hello, world from 8 with value 9
Hello, world from 9 with value 9
Hello, world from 10 with value 9
Hello, world from 7 with value 6
Hello, world from 11 with value 10
```

this is again not a homework . its some code i run into in some reference but posix is not my field so i just want what's enough to understand this
my questions are :

- what does this mean int f = *((int *)(i)); ??? i mean pointers written like these i cant understand them
- what does this mean (void *)(&i))
- does pthread_create return a zero or  non-zero value in success?
  -in the output let's take line one for example how come there is value 1 !! isn't it supposed to be zero since i is zero
- does ++i affect this output?

Comment: Firstly, please ask *one* question at a time, and secondly, learn about function pointers and also refer to the documentation for the functions you are using.

Answer (score 4):

> what does this mean `int f = *((int *)(i));` ???

It casts `i` to an `int *`, dereferences it, and assigns the value to `f`.

> what does this mean `(void *)(&i))`

It takes a pointer to `i` and casts it to `void *`.

> does `pthread_create` return a zero or non-zero value in success?

`pthread_create` returns zero on success.

> in the output let's take line one for example how come there is value 1 !! isn't it supposed to be zero since i is zero

You'd think so, but it isn't. Each thread is executing asynchonously from all the others, and is reading the value of `i` *at the time it runs*, not at the time it was launched; as such, the results are actually unpredictable. The program you're running here looks like it's supposed to demonstrate this exact effect.

> does `++i` affect this output?

Uh... yes? The loop would not terminate without it.

Comment: great answer but does this explain 9 being printed three times and 5 being printed twice??

Comment: Like I said, "the results are actually unpredictable". They depend on the exact order in which threads run.

Answer (score 1):

> what does this mean int f = *((int *)(i));

`int f = *((int *)(i));` means cast `i` to an `int*`, and then dereference this pointer to get the `int` value at the address. You can break it down into two steps:

```
int *temp = (int*)i;
int f = *temp;
```

> what does this mean (void *)(&i))

`(void *)(&i)` simply casts the address of `i` (in `main` that's an `int*`) to a `void*`.

> does pthread_create return a zero or non-zero value in success?

From the man pages:

> RETURN VALUE
>
> ```
>   On  success,  pthread_create() returns 0; on error, it returns an error
>   number, and the contents of *thread are undefined.
> ```

> in the output let's take line one for example how come there is value 1 !! isn't it supposed to be zero since i is zero

You're passing a pointer to `i` to the thread function, and since the main thread and this new thread are running in parallel, `i` can be updated in the `for` loop (`++i`) before it's accessed in `work`.

> does ++i affect this output?

Yes, it's the argument being passed to your thread function. It's the number after `"...with value"` in the output.

Comment: well about ++i : why is the first printed value 1 and not 0 and why is 5 printed twice and also 9 ??!!

Comment: ++i is a prefix operator, it increments the value *then* returns the new, incremented value. By contrast, i++ returns the value, *then* increments it.

Comment: @Armagadon: Sorry for the late reply. You're not waiting for a thread to finish before continuing with the loop and incrementing `i`. The only thing you can be certain about is that the number being printed is *greater than or equal to* `i`, since you're passing a pointer to `i`. It's the same reason as the second last point in my answer.

Comment: @Arafangion  well how come it is greater than or equal to i
see line 9 ,, 6 is printed while the preveious value was 9

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let's see:

```
f = *((int *)(i));
```

Since i is a `void *`, it can't be legally dereferenced, so it's first casted to an `int *`, which dereference gives a value of type `int`, as expeced. asting the address of i to a void * is the reverse of this operation; since a pthread function accepts a void *, but an address of an int is of type int *, this cast is nice to be done.

pthread_create return zero on success: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_create.html

Yes, ++i affects the output, as it increments i by one, thus the next dispatched thread function will be supplied as argument with a value greater than that of the the former call's. That's why 'value' is incrementing during the program.

Comment: well about ++i : why is the first printed value 1 and not 0 and why is 5 printed twice and also 9 ??!!

Comment: Because ++i evaluates to i+1, whereas i++ evaluates to i, and both statements increase the value of the variable. (this is what is called "pre-increment" and "post-increment". The answer for your second question is @duskwuff 's answer: threads are not guaranteed to be created one-by-one, exactle one after another. They take the variable's value whenever they're created.